# reset inputmap and actionmap (key binding)

Tags: java, key-bindings

Is it possible to reset the inputmap and actionmap if a new JPanel is created and added to the original frame? It seems to me that the inputmap and actionmap is static, which means there's only one of each and are shared by all the JPanels, am I right?

ex:

(this doesn't work)

```
game_compos(main_frame frame_)
{
    frame=frame_;
    refresh=1000;
    restart();
    if_restart=false;
}
public void restart()
{
    if(jp!=null)
        frame.remove(jp);
    jp=new JPanel();
    jp.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("N"),"restart");
    jp.getActionMap().put("restart",new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            if_restart=true;
        }
    });
    map=new map_utilities();
    roles=new roles_manager(refresh,frame,map,jp);
    frame.add(jp);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    if(if_restart)
    {
        if_restart=false;
        restart();
    }
    map.draw(g);
    roles.draw(g);
    try
    {
        TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(refresh);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Some of KeyStrokes are set in variables of roles_manager type to change specific values of variables. I need to reset it for the new roles_manager variable

Comment: No, each Action/InputMap is maintained by each instance of the component separately, perhaps you'd like to share a running example that demonstrates the problem you're having....

Comment: A newly created JPanel will have no mappings by default so if you are having some kind of problem it is of some other origin. Your actual question can be answered in about 30 seconds if you go pull up the documentation.

Comment: Well, let's start with, don't sleep in the EDT and especially not in paint methods. Don't call repaint in paint methods, this sets up a never ending loop of repaint request that will eventually consume your CPU